# Parse.com Respond to Push Notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, parse-platform, response

I would like to set up a response, via Push Notification, in my app.

User A sends User B a message.

User B opens the app (through the push) to a new page.

User B sends User A a response (as a push).

Right now I can open to the page, but I'm not sure how to get the data I need.

Here's what I get from Parse from the first push:

```
userInfo: {
    aps =     {
        alert = "demo says HELLO WORLD";
    };
```

In this case, demo is the username of the user that sent the first push. I'd like to get that, so that the app for User B knows who to send the reply to.

Here's my Push Code:

```
    PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
    [push setQuery:pushQuery];
    [push setMessage:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ says HELLO WORLD", [PFUser currentUser].username]];
    [push sendPushInBackground];
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to handle this from AppDelegate. There are 2 ways to receive data from the push notification.

```
//Receive Push Notification when the app is active in foreground or background
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
           didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

  if(userInfo){
   //TODO: Handle the userInfo here
   }
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Get the push notification when app is not open
    NSDictionary *remoteNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey: UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if(remoteNotif){
        [self handleRemoteNotification:application userInfo:remoteNotif];
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void)handleRemoteNotification:(UIApplication*)application userInfo:(NSDictionary*)userInfo{

    if(userInfo){
       //TODO: Handle the userInfo here
    }
}
```

Updated answer below:-

In that case, I think you should use `setData` instead if `setMessage`.

```
NSString * message =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ says HELLO WORLD", [PFUser currentUser].username];
NSString * userID =  @"userid"; //TODO: set Your userID here

NSMutableDictionary * dataDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dataDict setObject:message forKey:@"message"];
[dataDict setObject:userID forKey:@"userID"];

PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
[push setQuery:pushQuery];
[push setData:dataDict];
[push sendPushInBackground];
```

Comment: Right. I have that set up, but what I showed above is all I am getting in userInfo. How do I get the objectId of the user that sent the push?

Comment: See the Update above.

Answer (score 0):

A notification payload can contain dictionary entries in order to provide additional data to the receiving application.  This is documented in the [Apple Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1).

When you generate your Push message in Parse, you can add the objectID of the sending user, so that your payload would look like this

```
userInfo: {
    aps =     {
        alert = "demo says HELLO WORLD";
    },
    sendingUserObject:142Xyd23
};
```

Your Cloud Code would be something like this -

```
var pushMsg=user.get("username")+" says HELLO WORLD";
var pushData={alert: pushMsg, sendingUserObject: user.id};
var pushMap= {};
pushMap["data"]=pushData;
var deviceQuery=new Parse.Query("installations"); 
deviceQuery.equalTo("currentUser",destination);
deviceQuery.exists("deviceToken");
pushMap["where"]=deviceQuery;
Parse.Push.send(pushMap);
```

Then when you receive the notification in your app you can retrieve the sending object id from the `userInfo` dictionary -

```
NSString senderID=userInfo[@"sendingUserObject"];
```